# Save multiline output with spaces into array

Tags: arrays, bash

The file `myHeros.txt` contains three scientist names on three lines

```
Alan Turing
Ken Thompson
John Von Neumann
```

I would like save these names in an array of length 3. I tried

```
heros=($(cat myHeros.txt))
```

but that results in an array of length 7 as it splits not only at newlines but also at spaces.

Comment: In your case, it is just `readarray -t heros < myHeros.txt`

Comment: @Inian Thank you. I over simplified my problem. Do you know if I can feed the output of an awk (or sed) command on the right side of `<` in your code? Something like `readarray -t heros < \`awk 'NR > 10{print} myHeros.txt'\``?

Comment: Actually, I think the post my question was marked a duplicate of perfectly answers my question. Thank you!